# Importing NPM modules into Wordpress ReactJS Plugin

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, babeljs, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to use some of my React components, which I published to NPM, in my Wordpress plugin - I am trying to create a shortcode which will render the component.

I am following this tutorial and making adjustments: https://github.com/stcalica/wp-js-plugin-starter

In my `src/index.js` I have:

```
import { AwesomeButton } from "react-awesome-button";
console.log("Start the engine!");
wp.element.render(<AwesomeButton  type="primary">Button</AwesomeButton>, document.getElementById('test-react'));
```

In my console I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createElement is not defined
  at Object.parcelRequire.Focm.react-awesome-button (index.js?ver=1554053763:17)
    at u (index.js?ver=1554053763:1)
    at parcelRequire.J4Nk (index.js?ver=1554053763:1)
    at index.js?ver=1554053763:1
```

I believe this is because the Wordpress's version of React can't understand the syntax of AwesomeButton. Any ways around this? Do I need to do some more configuration with my babel?

MY OTHER CONFIG FILES:

Here is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@wordpress/default"]
}
```

Here is my plugin's main php file:

```
function wp_js_plugin_starter_url( $path ) {
    return plugins_url( $path, __FILE__ );
}

/**
 * Registers the plugin's script.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function wp_js_plugin_starter_register_script() {
    wp_register_script(
        'wp-js-plugin-starter',
        wp_js_plugin_starter_url( 'dist/index.js' ),
        array()
    );
}

/**
 * Enqueues the plugin's script.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function wp_js_plugin_starter_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-js-plugin-starter' );
}

/**
 * Trigger the script registration on init.
 */
//add_action( 'init', 'wp_js_plugin_starter_register_script' );

/**
 * Enqueue the script in all admin pages
 */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_plugin_js' );

function my_enqueue_plugin_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'wp-js-plugin-starter',
      wp_js_plugin_starter_url( 'dist/index.js' ),
      ['wp-element'],
      time(), // Change this to null for production
      true
    );
}
//add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_js_plugin_starter_enqueue_script' );
add_shortcode('test', 'test');
/**
 * Return the link to the class textbook.
 */
function test() {
    return '<div id="test-react"></div>';
}
```

Comment: did you `import React from 'react';`?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii Wordpress packages react in `wp-element` technically it should be there.

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii basically forgot to import the `wp-element` react function. `const { render, createElement } = wp.element;`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to import the `createElement` and `render` functions from `wp.element`, which is Wordpress's React library.